# Ember data JSONAPI complex attribute data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I have a data structure as follows coming back from the server for some filter functionality I'm writing. Where each filter-group has many filters.

```
data: [
    {
        type: "filter-group",
        id: "556d7f5fa1f9de08500ef4e8_1",
        attributes: {
            name: "Colour",
            created-date: "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            active: true,
            filters: [
                {
                    id: "556d7f5fa1f9de08500ef4e8_1_1",
                    name: "Red",
                    created-date: "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                    active: true
                },
                {
                    id: "556d7f5fa1f9de08500ef4e8_1_2",
                    name: "Blue",
                    created-date: "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                    active: true
                },
                {
                    id: "556d7f5fa1f9de08500ef4e8_1_3",
                    name: "Green",
                    created-date: "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                    active: true
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

And I have models set up as such:

```
// models/filter-group.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  active: DS.attr('boolean'),
  client: DS.belongsTo('client', { embedded: 'always' }),
  filters: DS.hasMany('filter', { embedded: 'always' })
});
```

And:

```
// models/filter.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  active: DS.attr('boolean'),
  createdDate: DS.attr('date'),
  filterGroup: DS.belongsTo('filter-group', { embedded: 'always' })
});
```

I'm new to working with JSONAPI, so I'm not sure if my data setup is the right way of going about this. I'm trying to loop through the filter-groups and then inside each, loop through its available filters, using the following handlebars template:

```
{{#each filterGroups as |filterGroup|}}
    <h6>{{filterGroup.name}}</h6>

    {{#each filterGroup.filters as |filter|}}
        -- Filter output here --
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

But each filterGroup.filters object is empty. What am I doing wrong here? Am I completely misunderstanding the way the JSONAPISerializer works on structures like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSON API, while you can embed data within an attribute, you can't/aren't supposed to embed full resource objects (i.e., objects with their own `type`, `relationships`, etc.). I'm guessing that's what's tripping up Ember Data.

Instead, JSON API asks that you put these embedded resources in the `included` collection (see below). This allows multiple resources in the primary data to reference the same `included` resource, without that resource needing to be included multiple times in the payload. So the server response should look like this:

```
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "filter-group",
    "id": "556d7f5fa1f9de08500ef4e8_1",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Colour",
      "created-date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "active": true
    },
    "relationships": {
      "filters": {
        "data": [
          {"type": "filters", "id": "556d7f5fa1f9de08500ef4e8_1_1"},
          {"type": "filters", "id": "556d7f5fa1f9de08500ef4e8_1_2"},
          {"type": "filters", "id": "556d7f5fa1f9de08500ef4e8_1_3"}
        ]
      }
    }
  }],
  "included": [{
    "type": "filters",
    "id": "556d7f5fa1f9de08500ef4e8_1_1",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Red",
      "created-date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "active": true
    }
  }, {
    "type": "filters",
    "id": "556d7f5fa1f9de08500ef4e8_1_2",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Blue",
      "created-date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "active": true
    }
  }, {
    "type": "filters",
    "id": "556d7f5fa1f9de08500ef4e8_1_3",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Green",
      "created-date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "active": true
    }
  }]
}
```

Then, you may have to use something other than the `embedded` flag in Ember Data to get it to pick up the included resources—I'm not sure. But this is definitely the way to do it from the JSON API side.

Comment: Just got into the office and given this a try. You had it almost right, but the "included" object needed to follow the same JSONAPI structure as regular data, ie. with an "id", "type", and then "attributes" object. Gave me a great place to start to get it working though. I've edited your answer to include those changes :)

Comment: Oh, and you don't need to use {embedded: 'always'} for this, it seems.

Comment: D'oh, of course `included` needs `attributes` too. Good catch @MalabarFront, and I'm glad it's almost working now :)

Comment: it worked perfectly as soon as I changed the data structure. Ember just picked it up and sideloaded the included data :) Thanks for helping.